# ReferenceError: Image is not defined while using Watermarkjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, watermark

I have given a particular path where the file exists but getting an error while using watermarkjs

```
watermark(['../uploads/file_1546929350511_Name.PNG']).image(text.center('watermrk.js', '48px Josefin Slab', '#fff', 0.5)).then(function (img) { document.getElementById('center').appendChild(img); });
```

the error is

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Nss testing\test\node_modules\watermarkjs\dist\watermark.js:351
      var img = new Image();
                ^ReferenceError: Image is not defined
at loadUrl (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Nss testing\test\node_modules\watermarkjs\dist\watermark.js:351:14)
at load (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Nss testing\test\node_modules\watermarkjs\dist\watermark.js:337:20)
at watermark (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Nss testing\test\node_modules\watermarkjs\dist\watermark.js:164:42)
at C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Nss testing\test\controller\updateController.js:60:7
at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Nss testing\test\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:53:37)
at listener (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Nss testing\test\node_modules\on-finished\index.js:169:15)
at onFinish (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Nss testing\test\node_modules\on-finished\index.js:100:5)
at callback (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Nss testing\test\node_modules\ee-first\index.js:55:10)
at IncomingMessage.onevent (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Nss testing\test\node_modules\ee-first\index.js:93:5)
at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Comment: Just a guess, but `var img = new Image();` should likely have an argument which is the image file you want to read or create. If watermark.js depends upon Imagemagick, then have you installed Imagemagick?

Comment: sorry, it's not working and got to know it should be used in browser end & thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the WatermarkJS module should be used in the browser.

From your question topics (express, node.js) it looks like you are trying to use it on the server side.

The `Image` is a global object on the window object and creates a new image to be used in the DOM or to preload an image asset. This is why the error says `ReferenceError: Image is not defined`.

I suggest you check out the [ImageMagick](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemagick) module which can be used on the server side.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance and got to know it should be used in a browser end, is there any way to add watermark to the image in server side

Comment: Thank you, I used gm (graphicsmagick) and everything working fine